# What is this KDE cursor theme with the colorful loading circle?

Tags: kde, themes, cursor

I'm sorry if this is an out of topic and maybe hard to understand question.

I once came upon this cursor theme on Ubuntu GNOME after installing a package which required some KDE dependencies. It installed along a cursor theme which is the most pleasant I've ever seen, but I always have trouble finding it again after a fresh install.

It reminds me a lot the Oxygen cursor theme like this one:
[image]

If I remember well, they have very similar shape but the one I'm looking for is a bit more simplistic. What I really remember is the loading icon, which smoothly changes the cursor into a colorful spinning circle, something like this:

[image]

Sorry about this overly ridiculous drawing, though it's quite hard to describe an image just from memory.

I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Possibly https://store.kde.org/p/1148692/?

Comment: When did you install that package? I mean the year. And did you install it via apt or synaptic?

Comment: @edwinksl Very similar but the main color is white as far as I remember. The name doesn't seem to be what I remember as well, but indeed *very* similar.

Comment: @Anwar I installed it via `apt-get` I really don't remember the reason why, most likely it was an optional dependency for a main feature of a Gtk application. It was around one year ago, but the cursor seems to be part of the main KDE GUI packages to come by default with the KDE dependencies.

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks, I found the one I was looking for in the description of the link you provided! It's the **Breeze** cursor theme. The circle isn't very similar to what I have drawn lol but I'm sure it's this one :) If you are willing to write an answer I can accept it as the correct one.

Comment: @BrunoFinger It's okay. You can go ahead and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor I was searching for is called [**Breeze** (obsidian)](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999991/). I found it thanks to [@edwinksl](https://askubuntu.com/users/15003/edwinksl)'s help.

The cursor is available for Windows here: https://az4521.deviantart.com/art/Breeze-Cursors-for-Windows-628166238

For Ubuntum it's available in the [`breeze-cursor-theme`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/breeze-cursor-theme) package:

[`sudo apt install breeze-cursor-theme`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/breeze-cursor-theme)